# bootstrap datepicker set todays date if textbox value is null

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to set the default date as today's date for a date-time picker if value is null for the text box.

```
$('.comdate').datepicker({
    format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    orientation: "bottom left",
    endDate: "+infinity",
    'autoclose': true,
    keyboardNavigation: false,
}).datepicker('setDate',function() {
    var ishaveDate = $('.comdate').datepicker().children('input').val();
    return ishaveDate != null ? ishaveDate : new Date();
});
```

but it show exception when i checking for the values.

```
TypeError: d.getTime is not a function

this.setUTCDate(new Date(d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)));
```

how can I set the today's date if value is missing in text box.

Comment: Which Bootstrap datepicker do you use?